# Book recommendations for Sumerian ME decrees

Tags: sumerian, babylonian, akkadian

What are some reasonably well-informed scholarly studies (books, book-chapters, articles)
on the Sumerian godly decrees ME,
preferably containing the latest archeological evidence and interpetation?
I'm interested in the worldview the MEs reveal, as regards the combination of
imaginary symbolism and practical life.

Wikipedia lists 64 such MEs, but has little analysis on most of them.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me_(mythology)

So has there been any progress since Kramer's books of 1960's?
Books and articles on Mesopotamian themes abound, so I'm asking for some time-saving suggestions
on the most useful & complete material.

Comment: The list of *ME*s on the Wikipedia page comes from [Kramer (1963)](https://archive.org/details/sumerianstheirhi00samu/page/116/mode/2up), whose list in turn comes from the tale of [Inanna and Enki](https://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/cgi-bin/etcsl.cgi?text=t.1.3.1&charenc=gcirc), which I believe is indeed the main primary source. Unfortunately it gives very little context: the relevant portions are just lists of names of things. And even those are [very terse in the original text](https://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/cgi-bin/etcsl.cgi?text=c.1.3.1&display=Crit&charenc=gcirc&lineid=c131.I.1#c131.I.1).

Comment: And also incomplete—there are plenty of lacunae in the story of Inana and Enki. I'm not aware of any analysis more recent than Kramer.